# Another limit to evaluate: $ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{x-\sin x }{x-\tan x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you evaluate? $$ \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x-\sin x }{x-\tan x}$$

The fact that x tends toinfty bothers me very much. I tried to "force a L'Hospital", because we know that the limit of a product between a function that tends to 0 and one that is bounded equals 0. So, how would you manage this limit?

Comment: You are wise to be bothered by $x$ tending to infinity in this limit.  It doesn't give an indeterminate form to which L'Hopital would apply, since the denominator assumes large positive, large negative, and all values in between.

Comment: That's right. I tried all sorts of manipulations but I haven't managed to solve it...

Comment: I'm saying the limit does not exist, as posed in your Question.

Comment: But Wolfram says it's 1...

Comment: Wolfram[Alpha] and I cannot both be right!  Good luck with your analysis.

Comment: Thank you. As soon as I find the answer Iwill post it

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The $\sin x$ in the numerator is small compared to large $x$ with $|\sin x|\leq 1$, so this will be negligible in any analysis.

When you analyse the denominator, think about the graph of the function $\tan x$ and think, for example, of the number of solutions of $x=\tan x$ and $\tan x =0$, and what the function does near these values.

Comment: Still, it doesn't ring a bell..

Comment: @Bardo Note that if $x=\tan x$ the numerator is zero, if $\tan x =0$ the numerator is $x$. In the first case your function is unbounded near $x$ and changes sign too. In the second case, for large $x$ your function is near $1$. You really need to sketch a graph showing $y=x$ and $y=\tan x$.

Comment: OK, I gotit but how can I manipulate the limit to achieve a rigurous conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

The limit does not exist, as $\tan{x}$ stays undefined for arbitrarily many large values of $x$.

Comment: but wolframalpha says it's 1

Comment: I get no substantive output for this limit from WolframAlpha, just "standard computation time exceeded."

Comment: Really? Well, I'm going to try tu compute via WolframAlpha again.

Comment: Still, Wolfram says it's 1..

Comment: Copy pasting from the question into wolfram alpha gives $1$ for me.

Comment: Well, we just broke w.a. haven't we?

Answer (score 0):

$$ f(x) = \frac{x - \sin(x)}{x - \tan(x)} = \frac{ 1 - \frac{\sin(x)}{x}}{1 - \frac{\tan(x)}{x}} $$

If $ x_n = n \pi $  we have, $\forall n \in N: \,\,\ f(x_n) = 1 $.

$ \forall \,m \in N $ we have 
$$ \lim_{x \to (m+\frac12 )\pi} f(x) = 0 $$

So the limit of $f(x)$ does not exist.